# USB devices often named incorrectly

Tags: usb, kernel, lsusb

As seen the below output, ***lsusb*** is incorrectly naming some USB devices as **HD USB Camera**.

```
Bus 001 Device 012: ID 0eef:c002 D-WAV Scientific Co., Ltd HD USB Camera
Bus 001 Device 014: ID 060e:0960 Transmonde Technologies, Inc. HD USB Camera
Bus 001 Device 019: ID 0b05:1939 ASUSTek Computer, Inc. HD USB Camera
Bus 001 Device 018: ID 04b8:0e28 Seiko Epson Corp. HD USB Camera
```

Any ideas on how to work around this and have devices correctly named?

Comment: Not causing any side effects but it's really annoying

Comment: annoying where????? You are not describing much. Are you seeing names in an application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out this was an issue from usbutils version 012, currently shipped by Ubuntu 20.04; The easiest fix is to update usbutils from source:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libusb-1.0-0-dev libudev-dev -y
git clone https://github.com/gregkh/usbutils.git
cd usbutils
./autogen.sh
make
sudo make install
```

`lsusb --version` output before updating:

```
$ lsusb --version
lsusb (usbutils) 012
```

`lsusb --version` output after updating:

```
$ lsusb --version
lsusb (usbutils) 014
```

`lsusb` output after updating:

```
Bus 009 Device 002: ID 060e:0960 Transmonde Technologies, Inc. 4010E
Bus 001 Device 009: ID 0eef:c002 D-WAV Scientific Co., Ltd eGalaxTouch P80H46 1160 vT4_M05 k4.10.143
Bus 001 Device 014: ID 060e:0960 Transmonde Technologies, Inc. 4010E
Bus 001 Device 012: ID 0eef:c002 D-WAV Scientific Co., Ltd eGalaxTouch P80H46 1160 vT4_M05 k4.10.143
Bus 001 Device 010: ID 174c:2074 ASMedia Technology Inc. ASM1074 High-Speed hub
Bus 001 Device 008: ID 174c:2074 ASMedia Technology Inc. ASM1074 High-Speed hub
Bus 001 Device 019: ID 0b05:1939 ASUSTek Computer, Inc. AURA LED Controller
Bus 001 Device 018: ID 04b8:0e28 Seiko Epson Corp. TM-T20III
```